# Retrieve table values from an unknown size table

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am in the process of creating a website and I have a HTML table that you can add a row to by clicking a button. There is an input box for every column in every row. When the table is submitted, it should retrieve all the info from all the input boxes and put it in an array that separates the rows.

I am positive that this requires a loop and I tried getting the children from the `tbody` element, but that didn't return the correct values.

```
function submitForm() {
    var c = $("#tbl").children;
    console.log(c);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very simple, just browse the rows of the array and the cells of each line.
So obviously I do not know what type of array you want, but I've made you here an example of a array with Jquery.

I hope it will help you.

```js
 $(function(){
  var datas = [];
  $.each($('#table tr'), function(index, val) {
    var childs = $(this).children('td');
    var array = {childs: []};
    $.each(childs, function(i, v) {
     //get your value 
     var value = $(this).text();
      array.childs.push(value);
    });
    datas.push(array);
  });

  //final result 
  console.log(datas);
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Resultat</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <table id="table" border="1">
   <tr>
    <td>Value1 line1</td>
    <td>Value2 line1</td>
    <td>Value3 line1</td>
   </tr>   
   <tr>
    <td>Value1 line2</td>
    <td>Value2 line2</td>
    <td>Value3 line2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Value1 line3</td>
    <td>Value2 line3</td>
    <td>Value3 line3</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified solution you could easily work into your form submission code.

```js
const tdInputs = document.querySelectorAll('td > input');
let inputValues = [];
tdInputs.forEach(input => inputValues.push(input.value));

console.log(inputValues);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="value1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="value2"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/1022151/

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming...

Since there's hardly any code in the question, I took the liberty to add what I consider necessary to which the question neglected to provide. If you don't have the setup like how my demo is setup, I recommend that you consider refactoring your code a little.

### Setup

The demo is fully functional:

- Adds and removes rows
- A `<form>` is wrapped around the `<table>` since there's an `<input>` in each `<td>`
- The `<form>` will send its data to a live test server when the `submit` event is triggered.
- The live server will send a response as a JSON which will be displayed in the `<iframe>` located below the `<table>`.
- This default behavior triggered by a`submit` event will be temporarily postponed by this function:

> ```
>    // Earlier in the code, this was called to interrupt the default behavior
>     event.preventDefault();
>     ...
>     /* .map() all inputs in the table...
>     | store all the strings that contain an input's name and value into a jQuery Object
>     | .get() the data from the jQuery Object as an array
>     | although optional, you can present it as a string by using `.join()`
>     */// Finally, submit the form data to the test server
>     var dataArray = $('.data input').map(function(idx, txt) {
>       return `${$(this).attr('name')}: ${$(this).val()}`;
>     }).get().join(', ');
>     console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
>    $('.ui').submit();
>      /**/
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
var count = 0;
var row = `<tr><td><input name='a'></td><td><input name='b'></td><td><input name='c'></td><td><button class='del' type='button'>&#10134;</button></td></tr>`;

$('.ui').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('add')) {
    count++;
    $('.data').append(row);
    $('tr:last input').each(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      $(this).attr('name', name+count);
    });
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('del')) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  } else {
    var dataArray = $('.data input').map(function(idx, txt) {
      return `${$(this).attr('name')}: ${$(this).val()}`;
    }).get().join(', ');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
    $('.ui').submit();
  }
});
```

```css
.ui {width: 100%}
.set {padding: 0;}
.data {width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; border: 1px ridge #777; border-spacing: 1px}
td {width: 30%; padding: 0 1px}
tr td:last-of-type {width: 10%}
.add {margin: 0 0 0 85%;}
iframe {width: 100%}
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 20%;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content:'';
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<form class='ui' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <fieldset class='set'>
    <button class='add' type='button'>&#10133;</button>
    <button>&#129146;</button>
  </fieldset>
<table class='data'>
  <tr><td><input name='a0'></td><td><input name='b0'></td><td><input name='c0'></td><td><button class='del' type='button'>&#10134;</button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<iframe src='about:blank' name='response'></iframe>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```